# woocommerce ajax product filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am creating a custom woocommerce ajax product filter widgets to filter product by category, price, brand, status (in stock, on sale) using jQuery ajax and WordPress wp_query to customize WordPress query
How to display products number beside categories and brands based on the current displayed products

ex: if user select a brand name from brand filter it should display the number of products beside every category that only exist in the selected brand

I already created all filter widgets and it working good but i cant display the correct numbers

what i am trying to do:

- I used this function to get all website categories then used foreach loop to display all categories in the category filter widget:
  get_terms( $query_args )
- then i used this function to get all current product categories in the current loop:
  get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' )

how to inject these current product category numbers inside every category in the widget filter ?

If there is another good way to do that please let me know